# Spring Jbpm6 integration Issue

Tags: spring, jbpm, business-process-management, circular-reference

I'm trying to integrate Spring and JBPM6 , but using Java-based style configuration according to configurations of https://github.com/droolsjbpm/droolsjbpm-integration/tree/6.1.0.Final/kie-spring/src/test/resources/jbpm/local-emf , but got unresolvable circular reference error when creating RuntimeEviromentFactoryBean, Here list my configurations

DataConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.test.spring.config.repository" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DataConfig {
@Bean
public DataSource devDataSource() {
    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:spring-jbpm");
    config.setUsername("jbpm");
    config.setPassword("jbpm);
    config.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
    return new HikariDataSource(config);
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
        DataSource datasource) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emf.setDataSource(datasource);
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
    emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(hibernateJpaVendorAdapter);
    emf.setPackagesToScan("org.jbpm.persistence.processinstance",
            "org.drools.persistence.info", "org.jbpm.process.audit",
            "org.jbpm.persistence.correlation",
            "org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.jpa",
            "org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model",
            "org.jbpm.services.task.audit.impl.model");
    emf.setJpaPropertyMap(getJpaProperties());
    emf.setMappingResources("META-INF/Taskorm.xml",
            "META-INF/TaskAuditorm.xml");
    return emf;
}

private Map<String, ?> getJpaProperties() {
    Map<String, Object> p = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    p.put("hibernate.max_fetch_depth", 3);
    p.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
    p.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
    p.put("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", false);
    return null;

}

@Bean
@Autowired
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
        EntityManagerFactory emf) throws NamingException {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public EntityManager entityManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    return emf.createEntityManager();
}
```

JbpmConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class JbpmConfig {

@Bean
@Autowired
public RuntimeEnvironmentFactoryBean runtimeEnvironmentFactoryBean(
        EntityManagerFactory emf, PlatformTransactionManager tm) {

    RuntimeEnvironmentFactoryBean ref = new RuntimeEnvironmentFactoryBean();

    ref.setType("DEFAULT");
    ref.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    ref.setTransactionManager(tm);
    // ref.setKbaseName("kbase");
     ref.setAssets(getAssets());
    return ref;

}

// @Bean
// @Autowired
// public RuntimeEnvironment runtimeEnvironment(
// RuntimeEnvironmentFactoryBean ref) throws Exception {
// return (RuntimeEnvironment) ref.getObject();
// }

// @Bean
// @Autowired
// public RuntimeManagerFactoryBean runtimeManagerFactoryBean(
// RuntimeEnvironment re) {
// RuntimeManagerFactoryBean rmf = new RuntimeManagerFactoryBean();
// rmf.setIdentifier("spring-rm");
// rmf.setRuntimeEnvironment(re);
// rmf.setType("PER_PROCESS_INSTANCE");
// return rmf;
// }

// @Bean
// @Autowired
// public TaskServiceFactoryBean taskServiceFactoryBean(
// EntityManagerFactory emf, PlatformTransactionManager tm) {
// TaskServiceFactoryBean tsf = new TaskServiceFactoryBean();
// tsf.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
// tsf.setTransactionManager(tm);
// return tsf;
// }

// @Bean
// @Autowired
// public JPAAuditLogService logService(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
// JPAAuditLogService logService = new JPAAuditLogService(emf);
// return logService;
//
// }

private Map<Resource, ResourceType> getAssets() {
    Map<Resource, ResourceType> assets = new HashMap<Resource, ResourceType>();
    assets.put(ResourceFactory
            .newClassPathResource("jbpm/processes/sample.bpmn"),
            ResourceType.BPMN2);
    return assets;
}
```

**Error stacktrace:**

```
15:43:09.290 DEBUG Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'runtimeEnvironmentFactoryBean' -- o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory 
15:43:09.292 WARN  Bean creation exception on FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'runtimeEnvironmentFactoryBean': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference? -- o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory 
15:43:09.293 DEBUG Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'entityManagerFactory' -- o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory 
15:43:09.293 DEBUG Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' -- o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory 
15:43:09.295 DEBUG Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'runtimeEnvironmentFactoryBean' -- o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory 
15:43:09.295 WARN  Bean creation exception on FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'runtimeEnvironmentFactoryBean': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference? -- o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory 
15:43:09.296 DEBUG Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager' -- o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory 
15:43:09.297 WARN  Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt -- o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:347) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:816) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:744) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:860) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:790) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:541) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:436) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:412) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:187) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1112) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:816) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:744) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
... 30 more
Wrapped by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'runtimeEnvironmentFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [com/spring/jbpm/config/JbpmConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager]: : Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:752) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:860) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:790) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:541) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:436) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:412) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:187) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1112) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:816) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:744) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
... 30 more
```

Comment: Well, I'm using Spring 4.x , does it conflict with jbpm6 ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, after I changed my configuration, it works, code as below

DataConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.test.spring.config.repository" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DataConfig {
@Bean
public DataSource devDataSource() {
    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:spring-jbpm");
    config.setUsername("jbpm");
    config.setPassword("jbpm);
    config.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
    return new HikariDataSource(config);
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emf.setDataSource(dataSource());
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
    emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(hibernateJpaVendorAdapter);
    emf.setPackagesToScan("org.jbpm.persistence.processinstance",
            "org.drools.persistence.info", "org.jbpm.process.audit",
            "org.jbpm.persistence.correlation",
            "org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.jpa",
            "org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model",
            "org.jbpm.services.task.audit.impl.model");
    emf.setJpaPropertyMap(getJpaProperties());
    emf.setMappingResources("META-INF/JBPMorm.xml","META-INF/Taskorm.xml",
            "META-INF/TaskAuditorm.xml");
    return emf;
}

private Map<String, ?> getJpaProperties() {
    Map<String, Object> p = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    p.put("hibernate.max_fetch_depth", 3);
    p.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
    p.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
    p.put("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", false);
    return p;

}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws NamingException {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
}
```

JbpmConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class JbpmConfig {
@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory emf;

@Autowired
private PlatformTransactionManager tm;

@Bean
public RuntimeEnvironmentFactoryBean runtimeEnvironment() {

    RuntimeEnvironmentFactoryBean ref = new RuntimeEnvironmentFactoryBean();

    ref.setType("DEFAULT");
    ref.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    ref.setTransactionManager(tm);
    // ref.setKbaseName("kbase");
     ref.setAssets(getAssets());
    return ref;

}

@Bean(name = "runtimeManager", destroyMethod = "close")
public RuntimeManagerFactoryBean runtimeManager() {
    RuntimeManagerFactoryBean rmf = new RuntimeManagerFactoryBean();
    rmf.setIdentifier("spring-rm");
    try {
        rmf.setRuntimeEnvironment((RuntimeEnvironment) runtimeEnvironment()
                .getObject());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    rmf.setType("PER_PROCESS_INSTANCE");
    return rmf;
}

@Bean
public TaskServiceFactoryBean taskServiceFactoryBean() {
    TaskServiceFactoryBean tsf = new TaskServiceFactoryBean();
    tsf.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    tsf.setTransactionManager(tm);
    return tsf;
}

private Map<Resource, ResourceType> getAssets() {
    Map<Resource, ResourceType> assets = new HashMap<Resource, ResourceType>();
    assets.put(ResourceFactory
            .newClassPathResource("jbpm/processes/sample.bpmn"),
            ResourceType.BPMN2);
    return assets;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Im working on an integration of jBPM inside a jHipster webapp, and got some question that maybe you have already answered. should I keep both transaction manager and data access definitions rigth? I mean the transaction scope of the whole app its totally different from the jBPM scope, and also, how you tell jBPM where to get the user data? I just saw this <bean id="identityProvider" class="org.jbpm.spring.SpringSecurityIdentityProvider"/> with a class that get the data from spring, is that the right direction? thanks.